# why when we call the "task" variable, it has to be written as "task()"

Tags: swift, function

I'm new to Swift and is trying to learn the concept of extension. I saw this code on youtube. My question is, why when we  call the "task" variable, it has to be written as "task()". I understand if I delete the "()" from "task()", the code wouldn't work. But I am confused as to why "()" must be included when we tried to use the variabe "task".

```
extension Int {
    func repetition(task: () -> Void){
        for _ in 0..<self{
            task()
        }
    }
}

3.repetition({print("hello")})
```

Comment: Variables can contain functions. When they're written like that they are called closures. There is a lot to read and learn about closures. When your variable contains a function and you want to call that function, you add the brackets and any parameters the function needs.

Comment: so the "task" variable itself is a reference to a function? Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: Yes, the definition of task is `() -> Void` which means it's a function that takes no parameters and returns no result (void).

Comment: Yes, `task` refers to a function. Take a look at its type declaration: `() -> Void`, meaning a function with no parameters or return value. When you call `repetition`, you are setting the parameter to `{ print("hello") }`.

Comment: @Michael Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @Thilo Thank you too for helping out!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables can contain functions. When they're written like that they are called closures. There is a lot to read and learn about closures. When your variable contains a function and you want to call that function, you add the brackets and any parameters the function needs.

Have a look at the documentation on closures [here](http://Variables%20can%20contain%20functions.%20When%20they're%20written%20like%20that%20they%20are%20called%20closures.%20There%20is%20a%20lot%20to%20read%20and%20learn%20about%20closures.%20When%20your%20variable%20contains%20a%20function%20and%20you%20want%20to%20call%20that%20function,%20you%20add%20the%20brackets%20and%20any%20parameters%20the%20function%20needs.).

In your case, the definition of task is `() -> Void` which means it's a function that takes no parameters and returns no result (void). When closures take parameters, you can refer to them by a name of your choosing, or positionally using $0, $1, etc.

Closures are often used in asynchronous functions to call back to your code when they've finished.